# When I fetch location of device, it always shows location set on Edit scheme of Xcode using Corelocation framework in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, core-location

I am checking on device not on simulator and I want to fetch user's current location but it always shows location which I have set in edit scheme field from target of Xcode. I am using below code:

```
- (void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
{
  //---- For getting current gps location
  // locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
  locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
      [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   //currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
   currentLocation=[locations lastObject];
   NSLog(@"location:%@",currentLocation);
   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
   //[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
   [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
   {
     if (!(error))
       {
         placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
         NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.ISOcountryCode];
         NSString *state =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.administrativeArea];
         //NSString *state =placemark.administrativeArea;
         NSLog(@"%@",Country);
         NSLog(@"administrativeArea>>%@",state);
         self.stateLabel.text=state;
         //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:Country forKey:@"countryISOCode"];
         }
         else
         {                 
         }
     }];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

How to fetch exact country and state information of user? [image]

Comment: Is it showing a popup asking for location access on device ?

Comment: yet it shows popup for allow location access,lbut only for first time.then it always shows location as per we have selected in default location as shows in screenshot.

Comment: Can you try changing the `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`  to `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` and you have stopped updating location once you get the location. Is it what you are want ?

Comment: no.i want current location of user means user is in which country and which state.n this is showing only location which i have set it edit scheme.if i set it to mumbai,india then it shows IN as country and maharastra as state and if i set San Francisco,CA,USA it shows US as country and CA as state.

Comment: If you want the real location of the device instead of the location setup in Xcode (how I understand your question), duplicate your scheme, untick "Allow Location Simulation" in the new scheme and build for the scheme you want (simulate location or not).